# Problems moving /var to another partition Ubuntu 16.04 LTS EC2 AWS

Tags: partitioning, mount, amazon-ec2

I usually create EC2 instances on AWS using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now they change the standard edition to 16.04 LTS, that I never used before.

I need to put /var in a greater disk, to support logs, etc.

As usually, I've created the instance, mount a disk on /mnt and copy the /var to it.

After that, I remove original /var and mount the device on a new /var. It's a simple procedure.

On Ubuntu 14.04 I never had any kind of problem to do it, but on 16.04 I've had a lot of error messages like this:

***cp: cannot open '/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/user.slice/devices.allow' for reading: Permission denied***

I'm doing this by root.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ... *"and copy the /var to it"* how, exactly? are you preserving file ownership and permissions?

Comment: Yes. I always did it on 14.04 LTS with no problems.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't answer this question, because I've just tried it. Using rsync -a to copy /var with Ubuntu 16.04 produces permission denied errors as described here.